# cstdio streams vs iostream streams?

Tags: c++, c, stream, iostream, cstdio

I just learned of the existence of the `ios_base::sync_with_stdio` function, which basically allows you to turn off (or on if you already turned it off) the synchronization between `iostream` streams that are used in C++ and the `cstdio` streams that are part of Standard C.

Now, I always thought that `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` in C were essentially wrapped in a set of objects in C++ in the iostreams classes.  But if they have to be *synchronized* with each other, this would indicate that C++'s `iostream` classes are *not* a wrapper around C's  `stdin` etc.

I'm quite confused by this?  Can someone clarify how C++'s iostream and C's stdio are *different* things that do exactly the same thing, just at a different level of abstraction? I thought they were the *same thing*!?

How it is that they have to be synchronized?  I always thought they were the same thing, one wrapping the other, essentially.

Comment: +1, woah I always thought the C++ `iostream` was a wrapper of the C `stdio` too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The C and C++ standards make no requirements on how things are implemented, just on what the effect of certain operations is. For the `<stdio>` vs. `<iostream>` functionality this means that one could wrap the other, both could be essentially the same, or that they are either entirely independent. Technically, using a common implementation would be ideal for several reasons (e.g. there would be no need for explicit synchronization and there would be a defined mechanism to extend `FILE*` for user defined systems) but I'm not aware of any system which actually does this. Having one implementation be a wrapper of the other is possible and implementing `<iostream>`s in terms of `<stdio>` was a typical implementation choice although it has the drawback that it introduces an extra cost for certain operations and most C++ standard libraries have moved on to use entirely separate implementations.

Unfortunately, both the wrapped and the independent implementation share a common problem: I/O is hideously inefficient when done one character level. Thus, it is essentially mandatory to buffer characters and read from or write to a buffer. This works nicely for streams which are independent of each other. The catch are the standard C streams `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and their C++ narrow character counterparts `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr`/`std::clog` and C++ wide character counterparts `std::wcin`, `std::wcout`, `std::wcerr`/`std::wclog`, respectively: what happens when a user reads both from `stdin` and `std::cin`? If either of these stream read a buffer of characters from the underlying OS stream the reads would appear out of order. Similarly, if both `stdout` and `std::cout` used independent buffers characters would appear in unexpected order when a user writes both to both streams. As a result, there are special rules on the standard C++ stream objects (i.e. `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, and `std::clog` and their wide character counterparts) which mandate that they synchronize with their respective `<stdio>` counterpart. Effectively, this means that specifically these C++ objects either use a common implementation directly or that they are implemented in terms of `<stdio>` *and* don't buffer any characters.

It was realized that the cost of this synchronization is quite substantial if the implementations don't share a common base and may be unnecessary for some users: if a user only uses `<iostream>` he doesn't want to pay for the extra indirection and, more importantly, he doesn't want to pay for the extra costs imposed by not using a buffer. For careful implementations the cost of not using a buffer can be quite substantial because it means that certain operations end up having to do a check and possibly a virtual function call in each iteration rather than only once in a while. Thus, `std::sync_with_stdio()` can be used to turn this synchronization off which may mean that the standard stream objects change their internal implementation more or less entirely. Since the stream buffers of the standard stream objects can be replaced by a user, unfortunately, the stream buffers can't be replaced but the internal implementation of the stream buffer can be changed.

In good implementations of the `<iostream>` library all this only affects the standard stream objects. That is, file streams should be entirely unaffected by this. However, if you want to use the standard stream objects and want to achieve good performance you clearly don't want to mix `<stdio>` and `<iostream>` and you want to turn synchronization off. Especially, when comparing I/O performance between `<stdio>` and `<iostream>` you should be aware of this.

Comment: Couldn't find a better explanation of the scenario. I once stepped into this trap and spent 3 days to understand what happened. Great job, Dietmar!

Comment: "what happens when a user reads both from stdin and std::cin?" , and how to verify this effect? use multi thread, right ?

Comment: @xusisme: the use of streams from multiple threads has no specific order promises. The synchronization between stdio and IOstreams applies when using obe if the standard streams from one thread but switching between stdio and IOstreams. You can verify the behavior, e.g., by writing individual characters alternating to `stdout` and `std::cout`: when `std::sync_with_stdio(true)` was called (the default) you’d get the characters in sequence and alternating, when it is `false` you probably get blocks if chatacters from `stdio` and `std::cout` (assuming the implementation buffers these streams.

Comment: @DietmarKühl What does obe stand for? 

Comment: @xusisme “obe if” should have been “one of” (I typed that on a phone and hit the wrong keys).

Comment: @DietmarKühl 

Comment: @DietmarKühl Whether it's necessary to call sync_with_stdio(false), if I just use std::cout in my program ?

Comment: @xusisme It isn’t necessary but most likely `stdout` and `std::cout` don’t share a buffer, i.e., they operate essentially without a buffer. If you do many I/O operations you can almost certainly measure a performance difference: in the past I have resolved long-standing performance problems shortly after joining teams by inhibiting flushes, once by simply adding `std::ios_base::shnc_with_stdio(false)` (they were logging to `std::cout`) and once by avoiding flushes caused by excessive use of `std::endl`. It is a while since I measured but I guess it still has an effect.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the  `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin` are the file handlers of OS. And `FILE` structure of C as well as `iostream` classes of C++ are both wrappers of those file handlers. Both iostream classes and FILE structure may have their own buffers or something else that needs to be synchronized between each other to make sure that input from file or output to the file is done correctly.

Comment: `stdin` and friends are structures of type `FILE` and a `C` thing. The os simply has file descriptors `0`, `1` and `2`, as defined in `unistd.h` as `#define STDIN_FILENO 0`.

Comment: correct. But also stdin, stdout etc are abbreviations to "standard input stream", "standard output stream" etc respectively. I used these words as abbreviations for system streams.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's what I've found.

Actually, the I/O is ultimately performed by native system calls and functions.

Now, take Microsoft Windows for example. There are actually available handles for `STDIN` , `STDIO` etc (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true)). So basically, both the C++ `iostream` and C `stdio` call native system functions, the C++ `iostream` does not wrap C's I/O functions (in modern implementations). It calls the native system methods directly.

Also, I found this:

> Once stdin, stdout, and stderr are redirected, standard C functions such as printf() and gets() can be used, without change, to communicate with the Win32 console. But what about C++ I/O streams? Since cin, cout, cerr, and clog are closely tied to C’s stdin, stdout, and stderr, you would expect them to behave similarly. This is half right.
>
> C++ I/O streams actually come in two flavors: template and non- template. The older non-template version of I/O streams is slowly being replaced by a newer template style of streams first defined by the Standard Template Library (STL) and which are now being absorbed into the ANSI C++ standard. Visual C++ v5 provides both types and allows you to choose between the two by including different header files. STL I/O streams work as you would expect, automatically using any newly redirected stdio handles. Non-template I/O streams, however, do not work as expected. To discover why, I looked at the source code, conveniently provided on the Visual C++ CD-ROM.
>
> The problem is that the older I/O streams were designed to use UNIX-style "file descriptors," where integers are used instead of handles (0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, and so on). That’s convenient for UNIX implementations, but Win32 C compilers have to provide yet another I/O layer to represent that style of I/O, since Win32 does not provide a compatible set of functions. In any case, when you call _open_osfhandle() to associate a new Win32 handle with (for example) stdout, it has no effect on the other layer of I/O code. Hence, file descriptor 1 will continue using the same underlying Win32 handle as before, and sending output to cout will not produce the desired effect.
>
> Fortunately, the designers of the original I/O stream package foresaw this problem and provided a clean and useful solution. The base class ios provides a static function, sync_with_stdio(), that causes the library to change its underlying file descriptors to reflect any changes in the standard I/O layer. Though this is not strictly necessary for STL I/O streams, it does no harm and lets me write code that works correctly with either the new or old form of I/O streams.

([source](http://www.halcyon.com/%7East/dload/guicon.htm))

Hence calling `sync_with_stdio()` actually changes the underlying file descriptors. It was in fact added by the designers to ensure compatibility of the older C++ I/O with systems like Windows-32 which used handles instead of integers.

Note that Using `sync_with_stdio()` is not necessary with modern C++ template-based STL I/O.

Comment: It might be worth noting that your source talks of "Visual C++ 5" and "CD-ROMs", just to put that in context.

Comment: @KerrekSB that's because it was written in the 90's. :) . When the STL was a 'new thing'.

Answer (score 2):

They *are* the same thing, but they might also be buffered separarately. This could affect code that mixes the use of C and C++ I/O, like this

```
std::cout << "Hello ";
printf("%s", "world");
std::cout << "!\n";
```

For this to work, the underlying streams must be synchronized somehow. On some systems, this *might* mean that performance could suffer.

So, the standard allows you to call `std::sync_with_stdio(false)` to say that you don't care about code like this, but would prefer to have the standard streams work as fast as possible *if it makes a difference*. On many systems it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

One *can* be a wrapper around the other (and that works both ways. You *could* implement `stdio` functions by using `iostream` and vice versa. Or you can write them completely independently.

And `sync_with_stdio` guarantees that the two streams will be synchronized if it's enabled. But they can still synchronize when it's disabled too, if the really want to.

But even if one is a wrapper around the other, one might still have a buffer that the other doesn't share, for example, so that synchronization is still necessary.

Comment: But according to the reference I posted in my answer, the writer says  the older UNIX-based I/O, which used integers instead of handles for the file-descriptors,  which caused incompatibility with Windows, so the designers added `sync_with_stdio`. Isn't it more of a compatibility issue?

Comment: It has nothing to do with unix-style io (file descriptors), which will never be synced with iostream unless you completely disable buffering. It only pertains to stdio (`FILE` level).