# C++, regarding fprintf and ofstream

Tags: c++, ofstream, printf

I've been using `fprintf` for a while now and I'd like to ask a question. What is the equivalent of this `fprintf` line:

```
fprintf(OutputFile, "%s", "SomeStringValue");
```

using `ofstream` ?

How to use the "%s" in `ofstream` is what I'd really like to know. How to take the next argument and print it as a string?

Comment: Something like `os << "SomeStringValue";`, where `os` is a properly opened [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream).

Comment: this really has nothing to do with `string`'s  consider removing that tag.

Comment: When you really need to fall back on non-trivial printf-style strings, you can use `snprintf` to build the string, and then output it on your stream.

Comment: Actually, you should use `fprintf(OutputFile, "SomeStringValue");` instead of your approach when the entire format string is `"%s"` or, better, yet, `fputs("SomeStringValue", OuputFile);` as this avoid parsing the string for format specifiers.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Is mixing C style `FILE` streams and C++ I/O streams guaranteed to provide consistent output?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Never mind, you already answered my question with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9654191/315052).

Comment: @jhx: By default you can read and write alternatingly from/to the standard streams using iostreams or stdio. The net effect is that iostreams is quite slow on the standard streams. Call `std::sync_with_stdio(false)` to disable the synchronization and make iostreams a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use it.

The equivalent is essentially:

```
std::ofstream x("your_file");
x << "SomeStringValue";
x.close();
```

Go read about it on any of several reference pages. Such as http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You just write the string to the stream.

If you mean you want to provide some additional formatting to the string (like right justified with space padding), then you can use the I/O manipulators `setfill(' ')` (set the fill character to be the space character) and `setw(length)` (setting the width of the output). If you want something that mimics the syntax of the C style format strings, you can use [Boost.format](http://www.boost.org/libs/format/).

```
std::cout << boost::format("%s") % "SomeStringValue";
```

Comment: That's actually kind of interesting and strangely useful for something else I am doing, thanks jxh.