# How do I use string format like printf while saving to a file?

Tags: c++, file, string-formatting

I am trying to save some `double` variables to a file, but I would like for them to save with only 2 decimal places. If I were going to print them to terminal I would do this:

```
printf ("var1: %.2f var2: %.2f\n", var1, var2);
```

I would like to know if there is an equivalent but to use while writing to a file with `fstream`.

I know in Java you can use `PrintWriter`, for something like that, but is there a C++ equivalent?

Also I know I am double dipping here, but if I could also get a Java `FileWriter` equivalent for C++ that would be great, because my program overwrites my file content, it doesn't append to it.

Comment: What is `fprint`? The C standard library provides `fprintf` which is available in C++ too. And if you know how to use `std::cout`, you can do just the same thing with an `std::ofstream` to write to a file.

Comment: open the file with `fopen` and use `fprintf` instead of `printf`

Comment: in c++, you will want to use std::ofstream and formatted insert operators  and io manipulators.  see  <fstream> and <iomanip>

Comment: I am just beginning to use c++ and I don't know the syntax all that well, some sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: @5gon12eder I know I can use `ofstream`, but I don't just want to write to the file, I would like to string format as well.

Comment: For string formatting, you could use a `std::ostringstream` or `std::snprintf`. But please be specific and limit yourself to one question at a time. Your original question was asking about file output.

Comment: Have a look at the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106102/how-to-use-c-stdostream-with-printf-like-formatting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263461/c-regarding-fprintf-and-ofstream   Also there is some info http://horstmann.com/cpp/iostreams.html and http://www.flipcode.com/archives/ostream_printf.shtml and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write your file in C style (using `FILE*`), you can use `fprintf()`.

For C++-style `ostream` output, such formatting is done with stream manipulators:

```
out << "var1: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << var1 << " var2: " << var2;
```

Sometimes this is inconvenient (such as when the format is language-dependent, and you need to retrieve it from the translation file).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `snprintf` to format the string in memory, then write it to the `ofstream` via `<<`.